# Return list of date using a set value

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

How can I subtract a number of months from a date, to produce a different date?

1. var date_A = 24-06-2016
2. var date_B = 24-01-2016
3. var x = 5

Please how can I use the value in x (number of months) to calculate the value for date_B, from the value date_A?

Comment: I have added an introductory sentence to clarify your question, and added the date-arithmetic tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `add_months()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions011.htm#SQLRF00603):

```
select add_months(to_date('24-06-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), -5) from dual;

ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('24-06-2016','DD-MM-YYYY'),-6)
-------------------------------------------------
2015-12-24
```

With SQL*Plus or SQL Developer bind variables (not sure if that's what you have) you can do:

```
var date_a varchar2(10);
var date_b varchar2(10);
var x number;

exec :date_a := '24-06-2016';
exec :x := 5;

exec :date_b := to_char(add_months(to_date(:date_a, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), -:x), 'DD-MM-YYYY');

print date_b

DATE_B
------
24-01-2016
```

if you want each of the previous five months, and the current month, you can use a dummy [hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332):

```
select add_months(to_date('24-06-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1-level)
from dual
connect by level <= 6;

ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('24-06-2016','DD-MM-YYYY'),1-LEVEL)
------------------------------------------------------
2016-06-24                                            
2016-05-24                                            
2016-04-24                                            
2016-03-24                                            
2016-02-24                                            
2016-01-24
```

Or if you actually have the start and end date, rather than the end date and `x`, you can do:

```
select add_months(to_date('24-06-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1-level)
from dual
connect by add_months(to_date('24-06-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1-level)
  >= to_date('24-01-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY');

ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('24-06-2016','DD-MM-YYYY'),1-LEVEL)
------------------------------------------------------
2016-06-24                                            
2016-05-24                                            
2016-04-24                                            
2016-03-24                                            
2016-02-24                                            
2016-01-24
```

Or you could use [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) instead of the `connect by` syntax if you prefer, and you're on 11gR2 or higher:

```
with r (dt) as (
  select to_date('24-06-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
  union all
  select add_months(r.dt, -1) from r
  where add_months(r.dt, -1) >= to_date('24-01-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
)
select r.dt
from r
order by r.dt desc;
```

You can use bind variables for the dates or upper limit in those queries too.

Comment: I want a list returned i.e. <br/> 24-06-16  <br/>24-05-16 <br/> 24-04-16 <br/>24-03-16 <br/>24-02-16

Comment: @OluAkin - it would have helped to show your expected output in the question; at the  moment it says you want a single date. Please edit your question to explain exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subtract `x` months from `date_A`, it's:

```
add_months(date_A, x * -1)
```

Edit: Alex beat me to it, and there is a new requirement :(