# How to loop a single output from a query

Tags: sql, oracle

Assuming the query below returns a single value:

```
SELECT date FROM dual WHERE name = 'max'

21-05-2011
```

How it can loop the previous single value result to return:

```
21-05-2011
21-06-2011
21-07-2011
21-08-2011
```

Comment: Kind of the reverse [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39128559/266304)? The mechanisms are the same, you're just adding months instead of subtracting them, surely?

Comment: Kindof. Except that the date is coming from a query

Comment: The date was coming from a query in my hierarchical and recursive CTE examples on that question. This doesn't seem to be any different really. (Except you aren't really getting the date from `dual` presumably; since that doesn't have a `name` column).

Comment: ..the result was coming from a query. In this case, I was to replace `24-06-2016` with `date`

Comment: I still don't see what the difference is. `select add_months(date_col, level-1) from your_table where name = 'max' connect by level <= 4` is the same mechanism. (As long as name is unique; if it isn't there's a workaround, but the recursive CTE is a bit easier to follow in that case).

Comment: I want to replace `24-06-2016` with `SELECT date FROM dual WHERE name = 'max'` in the solution to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128559/return-list-of-date-using-a-set-value)

Comment: The `dual` table doesn't have a `date` (which is a reserved word anyway) or `name` column. My previous comment showed how to get a date from a table and generate other dates from that - did you try that? It is still he same as what I was doing on your last question though.

Comment: `date` and `name` are just sample columns. `date-col` in your previous-previous comment should be the result from `SELECT date FROM dual WHERE name = 'max' `. I did this ` SELECT ADD_MONTHS(SELECT date FROM dual WHERE name = 'max' , 1-LEVEL) from #table_name` but I got a "missing expression error"

Comment: That is not what showed you. You can't put another `select` *inside* the `add_months()` call. `date_col` should be the name of the actual date column in your table, not the result of another query.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on comments, you can use the same mechanism shown in your previous question, just replacing the fixed date value with the column name and `dual` with your real table.

With your pseudocode:

```
select add_months(date, level-1)
from dual
where name = 'max'
connect by level <= 4
```

... but as `dual` is a real table that doesn't have those columns and `date` is a reserved word, it would be more like:

```
select add_months(your_date_column, level-1)
from your_table
where name = 'max'
connect by level <= 4
```

As a demo, I'll create a table with a single row that matches your filter and has your date:

```
create table your_table (name varchar2(10), your_date_column date);

insert into your_table (name, your_date_column)
values ('max', date '2011-05-21');

select add_months(your_date_column, level-1)
from your_table
where name = 'max'
connect by level <= 4;

ADD_MONTHS(YOUR_DATE_COLUMN,LEVEL-1)
------------------------------------
2011-05-21                          
2011-06-21                          
2011-07-21                          
2011-08-21
```

You just need to substitute your actual table and column names.